# How to read ragged right files using file helpers library

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I have to read ragged right files is there any way to read them using file helpers library

my Code is like this

```
[FixedLengthRecord()]

    class File_load
    {
        [FieldFixedLength(10)]
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)] 
        public string proj_name;

        [FieldFixedLength(30)]
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)] 
        public string iso;

        [FieldFixedLength(50)]
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)] 
        public string line;

        [FieldFixedLength(50)]
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)] 
        public string pid;

    }
```

if i don't use FieldFixedLength for last column it is throwing exception

Unhandled Exception: FileHelpers.BadUsageException: The record class marked with
 the FixedLengthRecord attribute must include a FixedLength attribute in each fi
eld.

Comment: Please show a minimal example and your code. A "ragged right" file is a file in which all fields are fixed-width, except for the last one. Try using a class marked `[FixedLengthRecord]` and all properties marked `[FieldFixedLength]` except for the last one.

Comment: i tried but throwing error

Comment: A fixed record size and all fields except one fixed length trivially implies that the last field must be fixed length as well. So what is the terminator of the last field? Linebreak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle your scenario with the `FixedMode.AllowLessChars` parameter of the `FixedLengthRecord` attribute.

Here is a working program  (I changed your field lengths to 2 for the example).

```
[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.AllowLessChars)]
class File_load
{
    [FieldFixedLength(2)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
    public string proj_name;

    [FieldFixedLength(2)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
    public string iso;

    [FieldFixedLength(2)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
    public string line;

    [FieldFixedLength(1000)]
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Right)]
    public string pid;

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<File_load>();

        var records = engine.ReadString(
           "112233444444" + Environment.NewLine +
           "1122334"
        );

        var firstRecord = records[0];
        Assert.AreEqual("11", firstRecord.proj_name);
        Assert.AreEqual("22", firstRecord.iso);
        Assert.AreEqual("33", firstRecord.line);
        Assert.AreEqual("444444", firstRecord.pid);

        var secondRecord = records[1];
        Assert.AreEqual("11", secondRecord.proj_name);
        Assert.AreEqual("22", secondRecord.iso);
        Assert.AreEqual("33", secondRecord.line);
        Assert.AreEqual("4", secondRecord.pid);

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```